# Splunk - Export events in received order

Tags: logging, splunk

I am working with an instance of Splunk that collects logs from a local server.
I noticed that some events are in the wrong order, e.g., some events are associated with a date in year 2020, while I know for sure - cross-checked with a local log - that they were produced a couple of days ago.

I am unable to retrieve all the logs from the local server, therefore I want to export the logs from Splunk, where they are stored after execution from the local server. However, the export (with the `| reverse` operation), produces a log where most of the lines are in the right order of execution, but ~20% of them is in the wrong order.

Is there a way to export the raw events, in the order they were received by Splunk, and not in the order based on the Splunk's timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a problem with parsing timestamps so Splunk is incorrectly reading part of the data as the year 2020.  Review the props.conf settings for the sourcetype to make they're correct for the data.  But that's not the question you asked.

Splunk has a hidden field called _indextime that stores when the event was written to disk.  You can sort on this field, but will have to copy it to a non-hidden field first.

```
<your search>
| eval indexTime=_indextime
| sort + indexTime
...
```

Comment: Thank you, at a first look, it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: I noticed that Splunk cannot help when `indexTime` is the same. I.e., some events with same `indexTime` will be in sorted in undefined order.
To extend one of the point of my question, is it possible to retrieve the full source? I see this can be done by selecting Show Source for each event, but the number of results is limited to 1000. In the Source, the lines are in the right order. This [setting](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Is-there-a-setting-to-increase-the-quot-results-per-page-quot/m-p/25992) might help

Comment: To handle duplicates, add another sort field.  `sort + indexTime _time`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, it does not work, probably because the events that are not sorted correctly are written to disk at the same time, so the first `+ indexTime` shuffles their order. Is there a field that we can use, that indicates their "index" number in the original log file? I am able to see them in the correct order by inspecting part of the source file through the "Show Source" view, and in this view they have the right order, so they must have some kind of index in the DB - but I am limited to only 1000 lines (without admin help - which I am not sure how feasible it is)...

Comment: There are four hidden fields in each event: _time, _indextime, _bkt, and _cd.  We've already used the first two; the second two describe the event's position in the internal DB and so are of no help here.  Anything else used for sorting will have to come from the data.  I don't know why Show Source shows events in sequence, but perhaps it's just coincidence.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you for your help